How to move the line next to the image at the top?
I have an image in the table. I want to write something to the right of it. Currently I have Title written next to it. I want to write at least 2 or three lines. But not sure how to do it. When I write \newline. It does not work.
How would I do somthing like this? I have created this in word but I want to keep the format of the table as in the latex code provided.


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.6cm]{geometry}

%noindent for whole doc
\setlength\parindent{0pt} 

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{wide=0pt, 
                  nosep, 
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label*=\arabic*.,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{picture.png} \textbf{TITLE}} \\
\hline
\hline
1. & Item1 & \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin=*]
                     \item detail 1.1
                     \item detail 1.2
                     \end{enumerate} &\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Two things would help: 1) add a screenshot, 2) provide the missing picture OR replace it by the sample images from graphicx. Thank you

Done! Thank you .

Using a \multirow cell could work here.

Your code still requires picture.png to compile. Replace it with e.g. example-image-a or add draft when loading graphicx. Why do you want to create a table in LaTeX which looks like one made in Word?! Also, your code fails to compile with an error.

You can achieve what you want with judicious use of minipages. However, I'd recommend reading booktabs documentation regarding the format of professional-quality tables. The example below demonstrates how to get a column-spanning first row with the elements aligned. It also demonstrates a booktabs approach, which includes code to get the list aligned with the text in the previous column.
Unfortunately or otherwise, an Okular-on-KDE bug means my images are worth zilch, so readers must unfortunately expend either imaginative or computational resources to visualise the result.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.6cm]{geometry}

%noindent for whole doc
\setlength\parindent{0pt} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|p{\hsize-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{%
      \begin{minipage}[c]{.1\linewidth}
        \noindent
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
      \end{minipage}\hskip 2.5pt
      \begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
        \textbf{TITLE}
        
        Something
        
        Something else
      \end{minipage}\hskip 2.5pt
      \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth-5pt}
        \raggedleft
        Some other thing
        
        Another thing after the other thing
        
        A final thing
      \end{minipage}%
    }\\
    \hline
    \hline
    1. & Item1 & \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin=*]
      \item detail 1.1
      \item detail 1.2
    \end{enumerate} &\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{p{\hsize-2\tabcolsep}}{%
      \begin{minipage}[c]{.1\linewidth}
        \noindent
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
      \end{minipage}\hskip 2.5pt
      \begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
        \textbf{TITLE}
        
        Something
        
        Something else
      \end{minipage}\hskip 2.5pt
      \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth-5pt}
        \raggedleft
        Some other thing
        
        Another thing after the other thing
        
        A final thing
      \end{minipage}%
    }\\
    \midrule
    1. & Item1 & \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt,noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
      \item detail 1.1
      \item detail 1.2
    \end{enumerate} &\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}




I took the liberty to add the output as images

@JasperHabicht Thanks!

I don't quite get what exactly the output should look like, but you could use a \multirow cell (to get the lines right, you could use the hhline package). However, I'd suggest that you look at the functionality of the tabularray package.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.6cm]{geometry}

%noindent for whole doc
\setlength\parindent{0pt} 

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{wide=0pt, 
                  nosep, 
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label*=\arabic*.,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.1\textwidth}|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\textbf{TITLE}} \\
\hhline{|~|====|} 
  & 1. & Item1 & \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin=*]
                 \item detail 1.1
                 \item detail 1.2
                 \end{enumerate} &\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Thank you for this!

@user292225 Thanks, now that you added more information to your question, I can see that this answer probably does not help you much. I leave it, maybe it can help others.

Thank you! I ended up using this since it works better with what I am doing!
